# Magento extension

Tags: magento-1.7, magento

I have created magento module as per the

[Custom Module with Custom Database Table](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/5_-_modules_and_development/0_-_module_development_in_magento/custom_module_with_custom_database_table#dokuwiki__top)

I have replace with proper variable, but I am not able to see, on able to create.

And I am using 1.7 community edition.

but on the admin panel two blocks are displayed.

how to display only single block

and also have problem that after saving and refreshing page title get change automatically

How to we debug if any error occur in processing request

Answer (score 0):

try to install module with module creator its very simple and easy,,,

Comment: Can you elaborate on that a bit?

Comment: just download module creator and run with your project just,ex;;localhost.yourproject.com/module creator and follow simple procedure and you create your own module without any error

Comment: I am using ultimate module creator and in that also there is error, actually "Mage::registry('current_newmodule_newmodule');" is not working and I am getting null object return to this